# Medios sintácticos para expresar la modalidad

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

Tengo que nombrar medios léxicos y sintácticos para expresar la modalidad en español. Encontré solo medios léxicos (*quizá* venga mañana / *ojala* venga mañana) y gramaticales (modo subjuntivo y el tiempo verbal). ¿Pero cuáles son los medios sintácticos? No entiendo =(

Comment: Reference: [linguistic modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality), [modalidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalidad). Tu tarea me parece demasiado complicada para resolverla sin alguna pista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sintaxis* se refiere al orden de las palabras dentro de la oración y dentro de las estructuras que forman una oración (generalmente llamadas frases o proposiciones). En castellano la sintaxis permite muchas variaciones de orden, pero generalmente estas variaciones se usan para indicar énfasis o cambios de tema (topicalización), no para indicar modalidad.

El único caso de medio sintáctico de expresión de modalidad que se me ocurre es el cambio de orden que suele indicar una pregunta. No es un medio puramente sintáctico porque generalmente va acompañado de un cambio de entonación. Tampoco es una sintaxis obligatoria en todos los casos.

1. *Los niños ya desayunaron.* → *¿Ya desayunaron los niños?*
2. *El gato está en el jardín.* → *¿Dónde está el gato?*

En el primer caso es una pregunta de sí/no y simplemente se invierte el orden sintáctico (es opcional: también se puede sólo elevar la entonación al final). En el segundo caso el interrogativo *dónde* reemplaza al complemento de lugar y al hacerlo se coloca al frente y hace que se invierta el orden sujeto-verbo.

Otra posibilidad sería la expresión de sorpresa que emplea un pronombre interrogativo (o una frase interrogativa) sin moverlo al comienzo como es habitual (esto funciona igual que en inglés):

1. *¿Hiciste qué?*
2. *¿Vas a volver a qué hora?*

Esto es expresión de modalidad porque no significa lo mismo *¿Qué hiciste?* (una simple pregunta sobre un hecho desconocido) que *¿Hiciste qué?* (un pedido de confirmación mezclado con duda, sorpresa o indignación).

Comment: tambien esta el de confirmacion ¿lo compraste, verdad?

Comment: @Mike Sí, pero ahí la función de expresar modalidad la tiene la palabra *verdad* al final de la pregunta. Es léxico, no sintáctico.

Comment: que tal en enumeramiento de acciones, por ejemplo : "lava la ropa antes" y "antes lava la ropa" o "lava la ropa primero" o "primero lava la ropa",  ...creo que esto va para el chat.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas! Pablo, ¿qué dirías sobre la construcción "tener que"? (por ej. "esta tarea tiene que ser resuelta" - expresando obligación o necesidad) ¿Es también léxico o sintáctico?

Comment: "Tener que" es una perífrasis verbal. Es léxico + gramatical.

Answer (score 1):

¿Puedes mencionar la fuente de donde sacaste lo de los "medios léxicos"  y "modalidades"?

Tengo entendido que las modalidades son como se utiliza diferentemente el lenguaje dependiendo del lugar.

El componente léxico son las palabras que utilizamos.

Por ejemplo, una diferencia léxica entre los diferentes españoles es el "Vos".

En cuanto a la sintáctica es la manera en la que están construidas las oraciones (el orden de las palabras).

Entre la mayoría de los países latinos no existen diferencias sintácticas ya que el español posee la particularidad de conservar el sentido a pesar de que las palabras cambien del lugar ... hasta cierto nivel.

Sin embargo existen diferencias entre la sintaxis en el español y el ingles.

Por ejemplo el orden de los adjetivos:

> auto blanco (español)
>   (Sujeto, Adjetivo)
>
> white car (ingles)
>   (Adjetivo, sujeto)

Sin embargo en español puedes cambiar el orden y aun es entendible y aceptada la oración; en inglés se vuelve confuso, sobre todo cuando hay muchos adjentivos.

> auto blanco pequeño y bonito
>   vs 
>   white small and cute car

Aunque tal vez todo esto sean sugestiones y una respuesta si no sabemos a qué se refiere con medio sintáctico.

Comment: Mike, mi profe nos ha dado esta tarea... No, la modalidad es otra cosa. „... es una categoría gramatical que se refiere a la expresión de la actitud del hablante respecto al contenido proposicional del enunciado“. Mira, hay medios léxicos que expresan la duda, la posibilidad y la probabilidad etc. Así, diciendo „quizá venga mañana“ el hablante expresa su duda (usando el lexema „quizá“ + el verbo en el modo subjuntivo). También se puede emplear los tiempos verbales („serían las ocho“)...

Comment: ... Y ahora tengo dificultad en entender cómo podemos expresar nuestra actitud ante el hecho de la enunciación mediante sintaxis